# Calculate % change in flat tables

Tags: pandas, flat

From df1 I would like to calculate the percentage change from, which should give df2. Would you please assist me?

df1

```
lst=[['01012021','A',10],['01012021','B',20],['01012021','A',12],['01012021','B',23]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','FN','AuM'])
```

df2

```
lst=[['01012021','A',10,''],['01012021','B',20,''],['01012021','A',12,0.2],['01012021','B',23,0.15]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','FN','AuM','%_delta'])
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your actual question here? Have you tried implementing this yourself? Please provide some more details as what kind of assistance you would need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `pct_change`:

```
df1['%_delta'] = df1.groupby('FN')['AuM'].pct_change()
print(df1)

# Output:
       Date FN AuM %_delta
0  01012021  A  10     NaN
1  01012021  B  20     NaN
2  01012021  A  12    0.20
3  01012021  B  23    0.15
```